# JavaScript - How to split a string in two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I need to split the string :

```
"[true,'3/5', 5],[true, '4/5', 5],[true, '5/5', 5],[true, '6/5', 5],[true, '7/5', 5],[true, '8/5', 5]"
```

In a bi-dimensional array:

```
[[true, '3/5', 5], [true, '4/5', 5], [true, '5/5', 5], [true, '6/5', 5], [true, '7/5', 5], [true, '8/5', 5]]
```

I have tried with:

```
var months = '[2010,1,2],[2010,3,2],[2011,4,2],[2011,3,2]';
var monthArray2d = [];

months.replace(/(\d+)_(\d+)/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
  monthArray2d.push([parseInt($1), parseInt($2), parseInt($3)]);
});

console.log(monthArray2d);
```

but without success

Comment: your data does not match the one in the code.

Comment: yes sorry a copy paste mistake

Comment: You can edit your question to show which is correct, the `[true, '3/5', 5]` format or the `[2010, 1, 2]` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use JSON.parse, since your string has '' around the strings, it needs to be changed to "" so a replace statement can handle it. This assumes your data will not have extra quotes in it.

```js
var str = "[true,'3/5',5],[true,'4/5',5],[true,'5/5',5],[true,'6/5',5],[true,'7/5',5],[true,'8/5',5]"
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + str.replace(/'/g, '"') + "]")
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: nice thank you one more :
How i can sum all the 2 property of all array element without loop ?

Answer (score 2):

Since your string is almost valid JSON, I would just change all the single quotes into double quotes, wrap it into an array, then parse the entire structure:

```js
const source_string = "[true,'3/5',5],[true,'4/5',5],[true,'5/5',5],[true,'6/5',5],[true,'7/5',5],[true,'8/5',5]";

const valid_json = source_string.replace( /'/g, '"' );

const array_wrapped = '[' + valid_json + ']';

const output = JSON.parse( array_wrapped );

console.log( output );
```